# GUI not loading for tomcat after successfully installing tomcat on EC2 instance

Tags: tomcat, amazon-ec2, connection

I tried installing tomcat server on an EC2 instance. After doing the setup, it got successfully installed and it got started. Please check below logs for it:

```
ubuntu@ip-XXX-XX-X-XXX:~/apache-tomcat-8.5.43/bin$ /home/ubuntu/apache- 
tomcat-8.5.43/bin/startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-8.5.43
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-8.5.43
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-8.5.43/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/bin/java
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat- 
8.5.43/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-8.5.43/bin/tomcat- 
juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

I tried taking the public DNS IP and tried hitting http://:9090 to check for the GUI but it does not loads up. I have changed the default port for tomcat to 9090 in the server.xml file. It works for me on the local but I need it to work it on EC2 instance.

can anyone assist me on this ?

Comment: have you allowed the port at the security group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cloud architecture, it is best practice to implement principles of least privilege. Meaning, always **only** allow what is needed.

AWS Security groups are virtual firewalls, that control inbound and outbound traffic for EC2 instances.

To allow port 9090 into your EC2 instance:

- In the AWS console, navigate to EC2 service (ensure you have the correct region selected, top right in the menu bar)
- In the instances menu
- Select the EC2 that is running your tomcat server
- In the details section that appears at the bottom of the screen, in the Security Groups section, click the security group(s) listed there.
- This will take you to the security group that is associated with the EC2 instance.
- Click the 'inbound' tab, and add TCP port 9090 to the list.
- If this is a public facing web server, the source should be 0.0.0.0/0